# Generic list for UserControl

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create `Class<T>` with `List<T>` and `Method Add`. Where I can add `UserControls` and not instantiated them on add. Just pass them as a class and instantiate them when I need them.

My problem is if I add them with `new UserControlBlaBla()`. Then for that `UserControl`  constructor is called and I need to keep it in memory when I need it  and if I need it and call method to run something on it when it is showed.

I would like to make generic Class with generic list, and add that `UserControlBlaBla` class and instantiate it when I need it.

I have this and it works, but when I need to create Manager class I don't know which type is it. If I put `Manager<UserControl>` and try to `Add(UserControlBlaBla)` it show `UserControlBlaBla` is a type, which is not valid in the given context. Which is okay, it's just works if I instantiate it because only then is type of UserControl.

```
class Manager<T>{
    private List<T> _step;

    public void Add(T userControl)
    {
       _step.Add(userControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to have you `Manager` class have a list of types and instantiate them only when you need them?

Comment: var manager = new Manager<UserControl>(); manager.Add(new UserControlBlaBla());

Comment: You also need to init the list. private List<T> _step = new List<T>();

Comment: @JavierCapello yes. I need list of classes of UserControl and instantiate them when I need them because I don't want to keep them in memory. I have 20+ controls. And I need maybe 5-10 sometimes.

Comment: @Han I don't want to instantiate them on add.

Comment: It's just an example. You can use previously created instance when calling Add().

Comment: @Han I want to add class to the manager. And when user needs it manager will Instantiate it and add it to the form.

Comment: I am not clear on what problem you are trying to solve OP. How does instantiating a control from a list solve the problem better than instantiating it with `new`?

Comment: @JohnWu. I will explain you - I have list with User Controls for steps, added in row. And I don't want to instantiate them on the add to the list. I want to be able to instantiate them when and if they come to the row for showing it. Bad approach is instantiate all User Controls and keep them in memory only for reason if user needs them. In this way (accepted answer) I can instantiate them when and if user need that Control. Hope that you understood problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. one way to handle this is to use a common type to all your `UserControl` types, that is an `interface`:

```
public interface IUserControl
{
    void OnPress();
}
```

now you don't need to use generics, you can simply do:

```
...
public void Add(IUserControl c) {...}
...
```

and if you want to delay instantiation then you could do some work around -- idk what the context nor reasoning is for your requirement -- like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ...

class Manager
{
    Dictionary<Type, Func<IUserControl>> constructorCache = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IUserControl>>();

    public void Add(Type userControlType, Func<IUserControl> construct)
    {
        // do some checking for existing if you want
        constructorCache[type] = construct;
    }


    public void Get(Type userControlType)
    {
        // check for existing
        return constructorCache[type];
    }
}
```

to add to the cache of possible instances to construct you do:

```
var m = new Manager();
m.Add(typeof(SomeUserControl), ()=> new SomeUserControl()); // lambda syntax
m.Add(typeof(OtherUserControl), ()=> new OtherUserControl());
m.Add(typeof(OneMoreUserControl), ()=> new OneMoreUserControl());
```

and when you want an instance of a certain type:

```
var construct = m.Get(typeof(SomeUserControl));
var ctrl = construct();
```

where:

```
class SomeUserControl : IUserControl {...}
class OtherUserControl : IUserControl {...}
class OneMoreUserControl : IUserControl {...}
```

did not test code and this is just a very basic outline but gives you an idea of the concept.

Comment: That is, I already had interface and add them like that in Manager, and I tough to make it more generic. But I forgot that I can store func. Great catch. That is, manager is okay now.

Comment: And for most important thing - Interface is mandatory because manager will use some of methods that are defined by contract. This is most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
class Manager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _lazyInstances 
        = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Add<T>(Func<T> instanceCreator) where T : class
    {
        _lazyInstances[typeof(T)] = instanceCreator;
    }

    public T Get<T>() where T : class 
    {
        return ((Func<T>)_lazyInstances[typeof(T)]).Invoke();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var manager = new Manager();

// register a creator
manager.Add(() => new UserControlBlaBla());

// get creator
var userControlInstance = manager.Get<UserControlBlaBla>();
```

Comment: Great. This is also great more generic solution than @mad.meesh is gave. But I have now some methods that are defined by interfaces, and all UserControls are implementing it and Manager use this methods. But this is also great example, will use it on different thing. :)

Comment: I'm glad you liked it!

Comment: If you change the type of the dictionary to `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` you can then use the signature `void Add<T>(Func<T> instanceCreator)` to make things strongly-typed.

Comment: Your `Get` method then needs to be `return ((Func<T>)_lazyInstances[typeof(T)]).Invoke();`

Comment: @Enigmativity That is a great tip! Thank you!